# How to convert object timestamp to firebase timestamp?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to convert the following timestamp:

```
Object {
 "_nanoseconds": 725000000,
 "_seconds": 1621386976,
}
```

to this timestamp:

```
t {
  "nanoseconds": 725000000,
  "seconds": 1621386976,
}
```

How can I go about doing this? I am stumped. I have tried `toDate()` and variations of this, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on reddit:

```
getTimeText = (timeObject: any) => {
    // Convert to time text once it's of type firestore.Timestamp
    const getTextFromTimestamp = (timestamp: app.firestore.Timestamp) => {
        return this.timeAgo.format(timestamp.toDate())

    }
    if (timeObject instanceof app.firestore.Timestamp) {
        // Check if Timestamp (accessed from client SDK)
        return getTextFromTimestamp(timeObject)
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(timeObject) === '[object Object]') {
        // Check if it's a Map (accessed from Cloud Functions)
        const seconds = timeObject['_seconds']
        const nanoseconds = timeObject['_nanoseconds']
        if (seconds && nanoseconds) {
            const timestamp = new app.firestore.Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds)
            return getTextFromTimestamp(timestamp)
        }
    }
    console.log('Couldn\'t parse time', timeObject)
    // Fallback
    return 'some time ago'
}
```